# is there a way to use regexp with aptitude?

Tags: apt, regular-expression, aptitude

I use an alias to find new packages whenever I update the package index.

```
[$] alias aptn

aptn='aptitude search '\''~N'\'
```

Now while this works, I also get a bunch of -dbgsym packages which come whenever I run the above alias as I have debug packages in my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
##### Debug packages #######
deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ testing-debug main
deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ unstable-debug main
deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ experimental-debug main
```

Now is there a way to tell aptitude that search the new packages but only tell/share those packages which do not have -dbgsym in front of the package name, something like libwebp5-dbgsym or libweed0-dbgsym to take as examples. If yes, then how ?

Update - I use zsh on my workstation but the answer works on zsh as well.

Comment: `aptn |grep -v '-dbgsym'` Excluding matches via negated grep query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by combining both patterns in a single command-line argument:

```
aptitude search '~N !-dbgsym$'
```

This causes the search to look for packages with are *both* new and whose name doesn't match the `-dbgsym$` regex. If the regex is added as a separate argument (`aptitude search '~N' '!-dbgsym$'`), packages match if they match either pattern.