# regexp with aptitude part 2

Tags: apt, regular-expression, aptitude

I had asked about regexp with aptitude [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298405/is-there-a-way-to-use-regexp-with-aptitude) and that worked beautifully. Now have i386 packages also in the midst. How do I make sure that i386 packages do not come into the picture. I tried the following -

```
alias aptn="aptitude search '~N !-dbgsym$ ' '!-i386$'"
```

as well as

```
alias aptn="aptitude search '~N !-dbgsym$ ' '~N !-i386$'"
```

Buy now with the either alias I see the new dbgsym and i386 packages. I DO NOT want to see them. Is there a way out ?

```
─[$] aptn

p   sed-dbgsym      - Debug symbols for sed
p   sed-dbgsym:i386 - Debug symbols for sed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the most important part of the answer to your previous question:

> combining both patterns in a single command-line argument

You need to run

```
aptitude search '~N !-dbgsym$ !~ri386'
```

By adding the patterns as you've done, you're searching for packages which satisfy either of the two patterns you give. In the first case, that's packages which are either new *and* not debugging symbols, or not for `i386`; in the second case, that's packages which are either new *and* not debugging symbols, or new *and* not for `i386`. You also need to use the `~r` search term to filter architectures, they're not part of the package name.

A more general form of that search is

```
aptitude search '~N !-dbgsym$ !~rforeign'
```

which excludes all foreign-architecture packages.